# Distribution of Sum of Squares of Uniform Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I need to find the distribution of sum of squares of uniform random variables.

Assume that $X_i \sim U(a,b)$ and I need to know the distribution of $Y=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2$.

$X_i$ are independent.

Comment: Do we have independence ?

Comment: @GrahamKemp Yes, we have